# Deleting a person from Google Hangouts without 'Blocking' or 'Hiding'

Tags: google-hangouts

A person whom I don't know sent me a message on Hangouts. So I was curious as to what it was about. So I checked it and it was obscene and I replied rudely. Now I deleted the conversation. But the person is still in my Hangouts contacts list. And I don't want to block or hide that person in case my dad decides I'm acting sneaky and demands I open those up. I hate that person and need them removed.

How do I remove that person from my Google Hangouts list without 'blocking' or 'hiding'?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an option to delete someone from Hangouts without blocking or hiding. To remove someone without blocking you have to hide that particular contact.

In order to remove a person from your Hangouts contacts list:

1. Open Hangouts within Gmail.
2. Hover over the contact's name.
3. Click the 3 dot menu.
4. Select "Hide contact's name".

For more see the Hangouts Help [Hide contact](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/2945109?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).